# 458 The Decoder UVA explain (line.charAt(i)-7)

Tags: java

Its Uva problem : 458 The Decoder.

> "Write a complete program that will correctly decode a set of
>   characters into a valid message. Your
>       program should read a given fle of a simple coded set of characters and print the exact message that
>       the characters contain. The code key for this simple coding is a one for one character substitution based
>       upon a single arithmetic manipulation of the printable portion of the ASCII character set.
>       Input and Output
>       For example: with the input fle that contains:
>
> ```
> 1JKJ'pz'{ol'{yhklthyr'vm'{ol'Jvu{yvs'Kh{h'Jvywvyh{pvu5
> 1PIT'pz'h'{yhklthyr'vm'{ol'Pu{lyuh{pvuhs'I|zpulzz'Thjopul'Jvywvyh{pvu5
> 1KLJ'pz'{ol'{yhklthyr'vm'{ol'Kpnp{hs'Lx|pwtlu{'Jvywvyh{pvu5
> your program should print the message:
>
> *CDC is the trademark of the Control Data Corporation.
> *IBM is a trademark of the International Business Machine Corporation.
> *DEC is the trademark of the Digital Equipment Corporation.
>
> Your program should accept all sets of characters that use the same encoding scheme and should
> print the actual message of each set of characters."
> ```

I tried to get explanation from google but failed. 
Why I have to minus 7 from character.

Can you please expplain?

```
public class JavaApplication1 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line;
    while(input.hasNext()){
        line= input.nextLine();
        if(line.isEmpty() == false){
            for(int i=0;i<line.length();i++){
                System.out.print((char)(line.charAt(i)-7));
            }
            System.out.println();

        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value of `7` is just an arbitrary char code offset that was used to mask the text of the string.

If you take a look at [any ASCII table](https://ascii.cl/), here are some mappings for a few characters.

```
ASCII      Char Code
 A      -> 65
 B      -> 66
 C      -> 67
 D      -> 68
        ..
 J      -> 74
 K      -> 75
```

Now notice that in your string, the instance of `JKJ` that becomes `CDC`, looking at the char codes, this is:

```
C   D   C     <- Original
67  68  67
```

If we shift all of these by 7,

```
+7            <- Modification
74  75  74
J   K   J     <- New Text
```